# Split data using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a lot of data I'm trying to split in CSV. My source data has this format:

```
* USER 'field1' 'mail1@domain.com' 'field3'
* USER 'field1' 'mail2@domain.com' 'field3'
* USER 'field1' 'mail3@domain.com' 'field3'
```

And here's what I'm trying to get as output:

```
field1;mail1@domain.com;field3
field1;mail2@domain.com;field3
field1;mail3@domain.com;field3
```

**Rules**:

1. `* USER` in the begin of the line must be obviously stripped;
2. `field1` and `field3` could be an email address, or can contain `'`;
3. `field1` could be empty `''`
4. the second field is always an email address;
5. each field has `'` on the beginning and ending of the field itself.

My idea was to strip `* USER` (`sed -e 's/^* USER //'` could be a starting point), then "find" the mail in "the center" field, and then catch the left side and right side into two vars. Last thing should be to strip beginning and ending `'` on the vars.
Unfortunately, I don't have sed or awk knowledge at this level. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

---

Here an example

```
* USER '' 'alberto.cordini@generaligroup.com' 'CORDINI ALBERTO'
* USER 'moglie delmonte daniele' 'anna.borghi@rpos.com' 'Anna Borghi'
* USER '' 'annamaria.cravero@generaligroup.com' 'CRAVERO ANNA MARIA'
* USER '' 'patrizia.dagostino@generaligroup.com' 'D'AGOSTINO PATRIZIA'
* USER '' 'piero.depra@generaligroup.com' 'DE PRA' PIERO'
* USER '' 'viviana.dingeo@generaligroup.com' 'D'INGEO VIVIANA'
```

Comment: If you're able to add a small sample, containing the cases/rules you added to your post, it will surely be easier to help.

Comment: i posted an example below

Comment: why use `'` and not `"` to surround names that could contain a `'` ? ... it's asking for troubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** You can use this awk for the provided input:

```
awk -F " '" '{gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $3);
              s=sprintf("%s;%s;%s;", $2,$3,$4); gsub(/'"'"';/, ";", s); print s}' file
;alberto.cordini@generaligroup.com;CORDINI ALBERTO;
moglie delmonte daniele;anna.borghi@rpos.com;Anna Borghi;
;annamaria.cravero@generaligroup.com;CRAVERO ANNA MARIA;
;patrizia.dagostino@generaligroup.com;D'AGOSTINO PATRIZIA;
;piero.depra@generaligroup.com;DE PRA' PIERO;
;viviana.dingeo@generaligroup.com;D'INGEO VIVIANA;
```

Comment: it's not working as expected. watch the example below

Comment: i must preserve the ' inside the fields (not outside)

Comment: Oh perfect!
One more question: is it possible to "trim" the email address/$3?

Comment: By trim you mean trimming spaces from the email field?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want

Comment: Ingenious use of the `" '"` separator.

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
$ awk '{print $2,$4,$6}' FS="'" OFS=";" file 
field1;mail1@domain.com;field3
field1;mail2@domain.com;field3
field1;mail3@domain.com;field3
```

Comment: Well. This works with a little change .`FS="\047"`. Some systems doesnt accept this. Atleast my solaris box

Comment: I like the fact you are using staring and ending apostrophe as FS. This works until user O'Hara uses his real name (Google xkcd Johnny Tables for a cautionary tale). Still gets my vote...

Comment: it's not working as expected. watch the example below

Comment: Did you see `'D'INGEO VIVIANA'` in the answer-that-should-have-been-an-edit?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed and awk and that would work but like you I don't use those often enough to remember (and I find them clunky). If you need a solution which you can put in a script to run all the time then how about a Ruby solution, I use a regular expression but you don't have to:

sample-data.txt

```
* USER 'field1' 'mail1@domain.com' 'field3'
* USER 'field1' 'mail2@domain.com' 'field3'
* USER 'field1' 'mail3@domain.com' 'field3'
```

parse.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$stdin.each_line do |e|
    matches = e.match /\*\ USER\ '([\w]*)'\ '([\w\@\.]*)'\ '([\w]*)'/
    if matches != nil
        puts "#{matches[1]};#{matches[2]};#{matches[3]}"
    end
end
```

From terminal/command-line:

```
cat sample-data.txt | ruby parse.rb
```

p.s. For me if it's a one-time-kind-of-problem, I would use Notepad++ in Windows. I would open the file, then record a macro, and play the macro to the end of the file, done.

Comment: No problem! Just wanted to give you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed "s/²/²S/g;s/\\'/²q/g;s/\*[[:blank:]]USER[[:blank:]]\{1,\}'\([^']*\)'[[:blank:]]*'\([^']*\)'[[:blank:]]*'\(.*\)'[[:blank:]]*$/\1;\2;\3/;s/²q/\\'/g;s/²S/²/g" YourFile.csv
```

Assuming there is no field 1 with `'` inside that is/are not escaped

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` example, it relies on the fact that there are single spaces between quote-delimited fields. If that's not the case then it needs modification to be more "flexible".

To avoid shell quote-escaping which is kind of ugly experience, I would put one liner into a file. -r makes it using extended regexp (avoid quoting `()`s). Single quotes inside field1 and field3 are preserved by regexp greediness (eat everything, including quotes until last quote :)

```
sed -r -f s.sed samp.csv
```

s.sed:

```
s/\* USER '(.*)' '([^']*)' '(.*)'/\1;\2;\3/
```